# What happens if 2 rays of light coming from an extended object intersect before hitting a reflecting surface?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Why don't we see any images in our daily lives if this can happen?
This question is asked in context of formation of images.

Comment: What do you mean that the light rays "converge"? Light rays are straight lines, so they may *intersect*, but after they intersect they continue in their original path unchanged (the cross-section of photon interaction is negligible). They do not get bent or "converge" into one new ray.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, intersect would be a more appropriate word

Comment: I'll write an answer explaining that nothing happens when two light rays intersect.

Comment: Every time you have ever seen an extended object, light rays from it were intersecting everywhere in the surrounding space. What do you expect an "image" to show you that you haven't already seen with your own eyes?

Comment: Why can't we see that image?

Comment: What image? What do you mean? Why would you call something an "image" if it can't be seen?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9t0q.png  hope this explains something

Comment: I think *maybe* I'm starting to understand what you're asking, and it has nothing to do with rays intersecting. Consider your eye as a point (to make things simpler). Each point in the extended source sends rays in all directions, but your point eye will only see *one* of these rays - other rays will miss it.

Answer (score 2):

When two light rays, each a straight line, **intersect**, nothing happens - after the intersection each of the original rays continues in its original straight-line path, uneffected. Neither ray can get deflected, reflected, or modified in any other way.

This is a basic assumption of geometric optics, but if you are curious about the underlying cause, quantum field theory has an explanation. In QED (quantum electrodynamics), when photons (the particles of light) hit each other, they do not "scatter" off one another and just continue on their original straight-line path. This is because the basic QED interaction is between a photon and a charged particle (such as an electron), and the second photon has no charge so it doesn't interact with the first photon.

Well, what I said above is **almost** true. There is actually a possible second-order interaction - each of the photons can split into a virtual electron-positron pair, and those can interact, and annihilate back to two photons with different trajectories. But this event is extremely rare and can be ignored for all practical purposes unless the beam intensity is extremely high (a huge number of photons) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics

Comment: I was asking about formation of images

Answer (score 1):

In a geometric optics model, each point on the object emits a diverging collection of rays. Rays from different points intersect each other all over space: there's nothing special about these intersections.

In an image, each point in the image corresponds (approximately) to a single point on the object. Points where rays from different parts of the object converge do not constitute an image.

Comment: So we don't see an image when 2 light rays from distinct points converge?

Comment: @Yuvraj What image would you expect to see?

Comment: the image of the object

Comment: @Yuvraj Which point on the oibject is imaged at the intersection of your rays?

Answer (score 0):

You can see those intersection points if you focus your eye on them.

Because the rays reaching those points come from different parts of the object, what you'll see is an image (on your retina) that mixes light from different parts of the object, i.e., a blurry image. This is one way of understanding why things look blurry if you misfocus.